# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' when creating Advertisement

Tags: c#

```
Advertisement a = new Advertisement
{
    userId = (int)Session["userID"],
    Brand = Brand,
    AdContent = filename,
    Duration = Duration,
};
```

Comment: Use `Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"])` or `int.parse(Session["userID"])`.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: When you searched for this problem, in what way did the answers not work for you?

Comment: Writing a question is the most important part if you need helps from the community, please you have to be more detailed and split title and question body

Answer (score 2):

Your `Session` variable is stored as `string` and needs to be converted.

You can use parse.

```
userId = int.Parse(Session["userID"]),
```

Do note: you have to be sure the numeric value is there, otherwise it will tbrow an exception, but your code already was assuming that.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Convert.ToInt32() function

```
Advertisement a = new Advertisement
{
    userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]),
    Brand = Brand,
    AdContent = filename,
    Duration = Duration,    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should convert userId from String To Int.

```
userId =int.Parse(Session["userID"]),
```

Or

```
userId =Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]),
```

Or

```
userId =Int32.TryParse(Session["userID"], out var value)? value :0,
```